# SFML Sphere projection being stretched, don't know why

Tags: c++, 3d, sfml, raycasting

I tried doing a little personal project of projecting a sphere onto an image using SFML from scratch using the basic knowledge I know.  I coded it up for the most part, but for some reason the sphere bulges out towards the left and right sides.[image: Screenshot]

After some testing, I probably am just doing something wrong but I'm not sure what.  I'd THOUGHT it would be fine if the screen size was the same width and height, but I was wrong, I guess :/

`main.cpp`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

using namespace sf;



#define s_l (6 * MUL)
#define s_h (6 * MUL)

// 3d Point in space
struct S_Point {
    double x, y, z;
    /// Vertex_Point(double x, double y) : x{}, y{} {};
};

// Distance from a point to another point
double p_dist(S_Point p, S_Point s) {
    return sqrt(pow(s.x - p.x, 2) + pow(s.y - p.y, 2) + pow(s.z - p.z, 2));
}


int main() {
    // Window
        // Main Window
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(s_l, s_h), "Conecept", Style::Default);


    // Sphere
    S_Point sphere(0, 0, 100);

    S_Point cam(0, 0, 0);

    Image image;
    image.create(s_l, s_h, Colour::Black);
    Texture texture;
    texture.create(s_l, s_h);
    Sprite pic;
    
    {
        double leng = 200.0;
        int x = 0;
        const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
        for (double i = PI / 3; i <= (2 * PI) / 3; i += (PI / 3) / (s_l - 1), x++) {
            int y = 0;
            for (double j = PI / 3; j <= (2 * PI) / 3; j += (PI / 3) / (s_h - 1), y++) {
                for (double l = 0; l <= leng; l += 1.0) {
                    if (p_dist(S_Point((-cos(i) * l) + i - (PI / 2), (cos(j) * l) - j + (PI / 2), sin(j) * l), sphere) < 50.0) {
                        image.setPixel(x, y, Colour((-255 / leng * l) + 255, (-255 / leng * l) + 255, (-255 / leng * l) + 255, 255));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Done!\n");
    texture.update(image);
    pic.setTexture(texture);
    
    
    // Main Window Loop
    for (;;) {

        // Events-

        Event event;  // array of all events
            // See if window has closed
        for (; window.pollEvent(event);) {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
                return 0;
            }
        }


        // Events
        


        // Events+

            // Renderer
        window.clear();
        
            // Objects to draw to screen
        window.draw(pic);
        
            // Display
        window.display();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI, you are not writing in the C language.  The C language doesn't support namespaces.  You may want to update your question and tags.

Comment: BTW, prefer to use `(x * x)` rather than calling `pow(x, 2)`.  The multiply can usually be performed in a couple of processor instructions.  The `pow` requires a function call setup and return at minimum.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Oops, yeah you're right lol (on both things.)  The C tag was just a mistake probably from trying to add the C++ tag and not noticing.  The use of pow was because when I was trying to figure out the math for this problem, I was thinking in terms of powers so that translated into the code.  I'll change it, though!

Comment: I recommend calculating the limits and other constants, such as 2*PI/3.0, and placing into constant temporary variables.  You compiler may do this for you, depending on the optimization setting.  Other expressions: `-cos(i)`, `cos(j)` and `sin(j)`.  No use in recalculating values that don't change in the inner most loop.

Comment: My first thought was "perhaps your monitor has some weird aspect ratio that results in non-square pixels". I might be on to something or I may be completely wrong - I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a different ray-casting method off the top of my head using slopes instead of trig stuff that I don't really understand.  It's not perfect, but the bulging only on the left and right sides issues was fixed.

```
// Optimize variables?
    const double l_l = abs(p_dist(sphere, cam));
    const double op1 = -255.0 / (l_l + 15.0);
    const double s_l_2 = s_l / 2, s_h_2 = s_h / 2;

    for (double i = 0.0; i <= 2.0; i += 1.0 / (s_l)) {
        for (double j = 0.0; j <= 2.0; j += 1.0 / (s_h)) {
            for (double l = 0.0; l <= l_l; l += .1) {
                // Current Point of ray
                S_Point line_p((i - 1.0) * l, -(j - 1.0) * l, l);
                if (p_dist(line_p, sphere) <= 9.0) {
                    const double c = (op1 * p_dist(line_p, light)) + 255.0;
                    const double ox = 1 / (light.x - line_p.x);
                    const S_Point vector((light.x - line_p.x) * ox, (light.y - line_p.y) * ox, (light.z - line_p.z) * ox);
                    for (double k = .1; k < l_l; k += .1) {
                        const S_Point vect_p(line_p.x + (k * vector.x), line_p.y + (k * vector.y), line_p.z + (k * vector.z));
                        if (p_dist(vect_p, sphere) < 8.9) {
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (p_dist(vect_p, light) <= 0.2) {
                            if (c > 255 || c < 0) break;
                            else image.setPixel(i * s_l_2, j * s_h_2, Colour(c, c, c, 255));
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```